# How to get GUID, VID, PID of USB wifi device in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, io, guid

I have USB WIFI device, and I have to control this device(connect, disconnect...)

How to get GUID, VID/PID, MAC address from all USB devices?
and control this device from the result of step 1?

Comment: You're probably going to have to look at IOKit